# CSS3 page-curl effect issues

Tags: css, z-index

I'm currently working on a site that uses the "page lift" effect with CSS3 (see [demo items 2-4 here](http://www.paulund.co.uk/playground/demo/css_box_shadow/)), and for my first page, it worked well.

However, I'm now trying to add it to an element that has a background color (the working ones have elements inside the `.lift` element, which makes the shadow sit beneath everything in the stacking context), but on the non-working element, the z-indexing seems to be having issues. It will go to one extreme (the shadows sits on top of the background; `z-index:1` on `.lift` element) or the other (the shadow sits below not just the element it's `:after`, but below *that* element's parent; no `z-index` on `.lift` element).

[Here's a demonstration of the issue I'm running into, with some notes.](http://jsfiddle.net/3eLAe/10/) The shadow should be under the white box, but on top of the blue one. Is there a way to fix this, so that the shadow in the proper location, without moving the background to the `.lift` element's child(ren) or adding an extraneous wrapper around the `.lift` element?

Here's the code:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="lift"></div>
</div>

.main {
    background: #00f;
    height: 151px;
    width: 400px;
}
.lift {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #fff;
}
.lift:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -2;
    width: 75%;
    max-width: 300px;
    height: 15%;
    bottom: 24px;
    right: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 20px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 20px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 20px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(3deg) skewX(10deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateZ(3deg) skewX(10deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateZ(3deg) skewX(10deg);
    -o-transform: rotateZ(3deg) skewX(10deg);
    transform: rotateZ(3deg) skewX(10deg);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You want a shadow for the white box inside the blue box, but right now the shadow either goes on top or goes behind the blue box?

Comment: @cowboybebop - That's basically correct, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the z-index of your #main .. overpassing your .lift:after

```
.main {
    background-color: #00f;
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding:20px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:-3;
}
```

I suggest you do not use negative values for z-index.

carry on

Comment: Your solution works for the particular fiddle, though it still breaks in the scale of a full site. Unfortunately, the site is quite complex, so I have to settle for a different, less than ideal, solution.

Comment: That said, you can't not use negative z-index for this effect, its purpose is to push it behind its parent element, which can't be done with positive z-index values. Additionally, negative z-index is allowed, per the W3C specs. Arguing against using negative z-index is about like arguing against negative margins - the technical reasons are no longer relevant, so what's left are arguments based on what is believed to be "more correct" and issues based on mistaken understanding and misuse of it.